# Can I set a value in localstorage to be binary true?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

My code does a check like this:

```
if (localStorage.isAuthenticated == true) {
   $scope.template = $scope.templates[1];
} else {
   $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
}
```

Can someone tell me if this is valid. If not then how can I set it to true or false?

Also how can I check if `localStorage.isAuthenticated` is not set. In that case I want the setting to be `$scope.templates[1].`

Comment: Have you tried it?  What happened when you ran this code?

Comment: Local storage can only store strings. Your boolean will be converted to a string on set, you will have to convert it back on get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `JSON.parse`:

```
localStorage.isAuthenticated = true;

if (localStorage.isAuthenticated && JSON.parse(localStorage.isAuthenticated )) {
   //great
}
```

I use the `&&` to check if the value is undefined. If localStorage.isAuthenticated returns undefined because it's not set, you get a false back.

Comment: What happens if the value has not been set ?

Comment: u can check that in the if. I've updated the response

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant

because localstorage supports only string, not boolean
 you can check this link http://www.acetous.de/152/localstorage-sessionstorage-arrays-und-objekte-speichern

UPDATE:

```
 if(localStorage.getItem("key")==null) 
         localStorage.setItem("key","true");
 console.log(localStorage.getItem("key"));//return "true"
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I check if it is not set ?

Comment: @marifemac if not set you will get `null`